# Write a 1k MIfare card avoiding sector trailer c#

Tags: c#, winforms, nfc, mifare

I am writing to a 1kb mifare card with has 64 block and i need to particularly avoid every 4th block which is the sector trailer i.e blocks 3, 7 ,11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39 ....., 63; 
I am already authenticating the blocks before writing to it.

am running a loop like this:
**Please, I need help avoiding the sector trailer, my code just loops through all blocks writing to it therefore damaging the card.**

```
        int block = 0;
        byte[] array = ImageConvert();
        string hex = ByteArrayToString(array);
        Image x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(array));
        foreach (byte[] copySlice in array.Slices(16))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(copySlice));


            if (block == 0)

                AuthBlocks.Auth4(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);

            if (block == 4)
                AuthBlocks.Auth8(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 8)

                AuthBlocks.Auth12(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 12)

                AuthBlocks.Auth16(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 16)

                AuthBlocks.Auth20(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 20)

                AuthBlocks.Auth24(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 24)

                AuthBlocks.Auth28(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 28)

                AuthBlocks.Auth32(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 32)

                AuthBlocks.Auth36(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 36)

                AuthBlocks.Auth40(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 40)

                AuthBlocks.Auth44(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 46)

                AuthBlocks.Auth48(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 48)

                AuthBlocks.Auth52(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 52)

                AuthBlocks.Auth56(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);
            if (block == 56)

                AuthBlocks.Auth60(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);

            if (block == 60)
                AuthBlocks.Auth60(readerFunctions_, KEYTYPES.ACR122_KEYTYPE_A, 00);


            block++;
        writeblocks(block, copySlice);

        }
```

This is my WriteBlock Method:

```
   void writeblocks(int block, byte[] data)
            {
                try
                {


                    byte[] buff = new byte[16];
                    buff = data;

                if (buff.Length < 16)
                    Array.Resize(ref buff, 16);

                myhelper.addTitleToLog(richTextBox1, false, "Update Binary");



                            mifareClassic_.updateBinary((byte)block, buff, (byte)(16));




                myhelper.addMsgToLog(richTextBox1, "Update success");
                    MessageBox.Show("success");
            }
```

Comment: Would test that avoids `block%4==3` before the call to writeblocks help?

Comment: You are calling `AuthBlocks.Auth60` twice, is that correct?

Comment: @HansKesting that's a good place to start, Thanks for noticing an error, I have corrected it